# Reading from files in C programming

Tags: c, file-io

I have a "Instruction.txt" file, of which I must read inputs from, the contents of the file are:

```
1
2 Pasta 4
3 1 Falafel 3
3 5 Fish 3
3 5 Pasta 4
4 5 Fish 3
5 1
5 5
```

The first line is always the same with being only one value.
How can I read the rest of the lines values when the number of values may differ in each line?

I tried to do the following:

```
fscanf(Instruction,"%d %d %s %d",&funcNum,&tableNum,name,&amount)
```

but it didn't work, as I tried to print it using:

```
 printf("\n%d %d %s %d",funcNum,tableNum,name,amount);
```

it only printed: `2 0 0`

without the name.

Comment: So, which is the question @Keanu ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "didn't work"?  Personally, I'm not a fan of the `scanf` family, so I would use `fgets` for input.  Then, *maybe* `strtok` or just manually parse the line passing numbers to `strtol` as it is pretty straight forward here.

Comment: You can either read the lines as lines (i.e. not expect any fields) or by knowing how many fields to expect. Can you explain when you expect more number fields? Then write your parsing code correspondingly. If you cannot explain, then I do not see how you could meaningfully use the input data. Or to put it differently: Please explain the meaning of the only one "2" before "Pasta" in contrast to the "3 1" before the "Falafel". If you do not know what the different number of numbers mean, then it will be hard to parse them. Parsing will fail at the latest at finding the right variable to store.

Comment: `Pasta` is not a integer, but `%d` expects a `int`. Always check the return value of `(f)scanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code, demonstrating a possible solution:

```
char token[1024] = "";
int i = 0;
char c = "1";
fscanf("%c", &c);
while (c != ' ' && c != '\n') {
    token[i] = c;
    token[i + 1] = '\0';
    i++;
    fscanf("%c", &c);
}
int number = 0;
if (sscanf(token, "%d", &number) == 1) { // Token is an int
    printf("%d ", number);
} else { // Token is a string
    printf("%s ", token);
}
```

As you can see, we read chars until we reach space or end of line symbol, storing result in a string (char array). Then we use sscanf to read an int from this string. If sscanf return, it means that it read successfully and this token is a number, otherwise it is a word